# Usercontrol that doesn't implement MVVM in a caliburn micro application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a user control that doesn't implement MVVM (so I only have a class called ViewerControl.
In the **View** I add this code:

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ViewerControl}"  />
```

And in the **viewModel** I have:

```
public ImageSourceViewModel() 
{ 
    this.ViewerControl = new ViewerControl();
}

public ViewerControl ViewerControl { get; private set; }
```

but when I run the application, I'm getting this error:

> Can not find view for ViewerControl

Please note that my aim is to show this UserControl on my view and can play with its properties on ViewModel.

Comment: Can't you directly use `ViewerControl` in your XAML in this manner: `<ViewerControl ...>...</ViewerControl>`?

Comment: @Pragmateek Yes I can do, but then how to use it in ViewModel? The only solution that I have at the moment is to use GetView in VodeModel and the cast it to my own view and get ViewerControl. But it is very ugly. is there any better solution?

Comment: If you have to access a View element (which every Control Object is), then you are not using MVVM pattern. A control is only to be used in the View (XAML Code).

Comment: @mans You could simply do: `<ContentControl><ViewerControl></ViewerControl></ContentControl>`. But give us more information on your intent so that we can provide more targeted answers.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to access a UI control in the VM, that isn't MVVM. Does the control expose Dependency Properties, so that you can bind properties in your VM to those DPs on the control?

Comment: @Mashton the control doesn't expose dependency properties so I can not use it in a MVVM view. The application uses MVVM, so I created a new ControlClass that is MVVM (has both View and ViewModel) and I am trying to convert the user control from a usercontrol which is not supporting MVVM to one that support MVVM. I am looking for the simplest way of doing this as I can write code to expose all required properties in my VM and internally bind them to control. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: does this usercontrol actually use XAML? The reason it doesn't find the view cause it looking based on the convention for view/viewmodel that CM employs (totally configurable) but it is looking for a view named ImageSourceView.xaml.  Also note it is a function of magic strings of the namespace each exist.  AppName.Views.ImageSourceView / AppName.ViewModels.ImageSourceViewModel  ex.

Comment: @mvermef Yes the Im,ageSourceView and ImageSourceVideModel both exist and they can find each other (If I remove ViewerControl and put say a textbox, everything works perfectly) But I have a control (ViewerControl) that doesn't implement View and ViewModel and I want to use it in my View and be able to control its properties from VM. I am looking for the simplest way to do this.

Comment: As @Mashton said there is no easy way other than creating the DPs necessary to bring it into MVVM usability.  Is this a Forms Control? You might have an option with Interoperability. It could also be more trouble than it is worth.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750944(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the above is a long shot and it might actually be really unstable in the end.